# Benefits of using the high level entity framework over raw SQL

Tags: entity, sql, databases

Has anyone that has used both SQL particularly TSQL used in Microsoft SQL Server and Wolfram Database integration into its Entity framework, provide some particular examples where the high level structure makes writing the query easier in following ways.

- Make complex query compact.
- Make complex queries more readable.
- Makes easier to make queries dynamic.
- Make easier to modify large complex queries.
- or any other benefits of Functional Syntax of Entity Framework over Declarative Key Word Syntax of SQL.

As I understand SQL language is also a super high level language that has automated all of the database related operations. But the effort being put by Wolfram Research into its Entity Framework must be adding something more or bypassing some of the weaknesses of the naked SQL.

I would prefer non-trivial examples like doing complex external or self joins or some complex use of recursive common table expressions etc. Please provide examples from your own use of SQL, possibly the most sophisticated query you have ever written. But please apply to a minimal set of example tables necessary to demonstrate it so it can be easily understood.

Comment: A key consideration will be data size. Can you give some indications please

Comment: *But the effort being put by Wolfram Research into its Entity Framework must be adding something more or bypassing some of the weaknesses of the naked SQL* Or it may simply be a result of commercial imperatives to extend the scope of the Wolfram system and to push out competing products.